# JSON Hierarchical from Adjacency List

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have adjacency Data. with ID's and Parent ID's,

I trying to turn it into Hierarchical data, with nested JSON.

I have it working but when i have different objects with the same ID's but different parent ID's. The data get mixed up. Here is my Jfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Chris1807/e6s8qom3/2/

```
var makeTree = (function() {
  var isArray = function(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == "[object Array]";
  };
  var clone = function(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  };
  var buildTree = function(catalog, structure, start) {
    return (structure[start] || []).map(function(nodeid, index) {
      var record = catalog[nodeid];
      var keys = structure[start][index];
      var children = isArray(keys) ? keys.map(function(key) {
        return buildTree(catalog, structure, key);
      }) : buildTree(catalog, structure, keys);
      if (children.length) {
        record.children = children;
      }
      return record;
    })
  };
  return function(flat) {
    var catalog = flat.reduce(function(catalog, record) {
      catalog[record.nodeid] = clone(record);
      delete(catalog[record.nodeid].parentid);
      return catalog;
    }, {});
    var structure = flat.reduce(function(tree, record) {
      (tree[record.parentid] = tree[record.parentid] || []).push(record.nodeid);
      return tree;
    }, {});
    return buildTree(catalog, structure, '#'); // this might be oversimplified.
  }
}());


var flat = [{
  nodeid: "123802475",
  parent: "#",
  parentid: "#",
  text: "CONNECTOR",
  typepart: "Component",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-leaf",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123802476",
  parent: "123802475",
  parentid: "123802475",
  text: "PLATE",
  typepart: "SemiComponent",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-fire",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "90615593",
  parent: "123802476",
  parentid: "123802476",
  text: "C3604",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1396",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Copper",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1762",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Iron",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1061",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Lead",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3281499",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Zinc (metal)",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3402",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Tin",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "9505195",
  parent: "123802476",
  parentid: "123802476",
  text: "e-plate Sn (electrodeposited Tin Coatings, bright and matt)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3065",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Sulphur",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1061",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Lead",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3402",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Tin",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "749088",
  parent: "123802476",
  parentid: "123802476",
  text: "e-plate Ni (bright) (electrodeposited Nickel bright)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3112",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nitrogen",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3065",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Sulphur",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "2619",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nickel",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123802477",
  parent: "123802475",
  parentid: "123802475",
  text: "INSULATOR",
  typepart: "SemiComponent",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-fire",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123799238",
  parent: "123802477",
  parentid: "123802477",
  text: "Polypropylene",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "238",
  parent: "123799238",
  parentid: "123799238",
  text: "Polypropylene",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "9999",
  parent: "123799238",
  parentid: "123799238",
  text: "Misc., not to declare",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123802478",
  parent: "123802475",
  parentid: "123802475",
  text: "LOCK COVER",
  typepart: "SemiComponent",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-fire",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123795153",
  parent: "123802478",
  parentid: "123802478",
  text: "Pa46-GF30",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "33167",
  parent: "123795153",
  parentid: "123795153",
  text: "Polytetramethylene adipic acid dimide",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "23374",
  parent: "123795153",
  parentid: "123795153",
  text: "GF-Fibre",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "883",
  parent: "123795153",
  parentid: "123795153",
  text: "Antimonytrioxide",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1432179",
  parent: "123795153",
  parentid: "123795153",
  text: "Brominated Epoxy",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1226985",
  parent: "123795153",
  parentid: "123795153",
  text: "Pigment portion, not to declare",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123802479",
  parent: "123802475",
  parentid: "123802475",
  text: "CONTACT PIN",
  typepart: "SemiComponent",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-fire",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "90615593",
  parent: "123802479",
  parentid: "123802479",
  text: "C3604",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1396",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Copper",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1762",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Iron",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1061",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Lead",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3281499",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Zinc (metal)",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3402",
  parent: "90615593",
  parentid: "90615593",
  text: "Tin",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "749088",
  parent: "123802479",
  parentid: "123802479",
  text: "e-plate Ni (bright) (electrodeposited Nickel bright)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3112",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nitrogen",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3065",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Sulphur",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "2619",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nickel",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "757906",
  parent: "123802479",
  parentid: "123802479",
  text: "e-plate Au (functional) (electrodeposited functional Gold Coatings)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "757906",
  parentid: "757906",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3112",
  parent: "757906",
  parentid: "757906",
  text: "Nitrogen",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "10153",
  parent: "757906",
  parentid: "757906",
  text: "Gold",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "123802480",
  parent: "123802475",
  parentid: "123802475",
  text: "BODY",
  typepart: "SemiComponent",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-fire",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "73794193",
  parent: "123802480",
  parentid: "123802480",
  text: "C5191",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1396",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Copper",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1762",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Iron",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1061",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Lead",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3281499",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Zinc (metal)",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3402",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Tin",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "2835",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Phosphorus",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "9999",
  parent: "73794193",
  parentid: "73794193",
  text: "Misc., not to declare",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "9505195",
  parent: "123802480",
  parentid: "123802480",
  text: "e-plate Sn (electrodeposited Tin Coatings, bright and matt)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3065",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Sulphur",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1061",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Lead",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3402",
  parent: "9505195",
  parentid: "9505195",
  text: "Tin",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "749088",
  parent: "123802480",
  parentid: "123802480",
  text: "e-plate Ni (bright) (electrodeposited Nickel bright)",
  typepart: "Material",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-grain",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "1995",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Carbon",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3112",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nitrogen",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "3065",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Sulphur",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}, {
  nodeid: "2619",
  parent: "749088",
  parentid: "749088",
  text: "Nickel",
  typepart: "Substance",
  icon: "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk",
  Count: 0,
  state: null
}];
```

Comment: If `nodeid` is not unique, then what will you do if you have a `parentid` referring to such a non-unique value?

Comment: @trincot The parent id are unique.   A nodeID that has a parent ID should attached to that particular parent ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use real unique keys in the `catalog` object, to avoid that you overwrite previously stored objects. As you wrote that `nodeid` values are guaranteed to be unique when they have children, you could just prefix any `nodeid` with the `parentid` to make your `catalog` keys unique.

So, only three lines need to change:

```
  var record = catalog[start + '/' + nodeid];
```

and:

```
  catalog[record.parentid + '/' + record.nodeid] = clone(record);
  delete(catalog[record.parentid + '/' + record.nodeid].parentid);
```

That's it.

As a performance improvement I would suggest not to use JSON text conversion to copy objects, but to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead:

```
var clone = function(obj) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj);
};
```

Comment: thanks but now I have duplicates on the last levels. Reference my updated Jfiddle.

Comment: Can you please give the id where things are wrong, so I don't have to look for it?

Comment: "nodeid": "3402",   and again thanks for what you have done so far.

Comment: 1396: the source data already has this duplicate, together with the same  `parentid` (90615593), which you said in comments was not possible, so it is normal you get duplicates in the output.

Comment: you are absolutley right, I didnt see. that. It should be Ill figure it out. Thanks for all you help.